# Python to R equivalent : [i for i, e in enumerate(y) if e != 0]

Tags: python, r

In Python, I have this code: `[i for i, e in enumerate(y) if e != 0]`

This is within defining a function. How would this be done in R?

The function I am creating is (I want "possible" to be whatever the python code translates to):

```
bottom11 <- function(p,remain,final) {
  possible <- 
  seed <- min(possible)
  remain[i][seed] <- remain[i][seed] + final
  p[seed] <- 0
  return(remain)
}
```

Comment: [lukesingham.com:Anonymous Functions in R and Python, 13/8/2017](https://lukesingham.com/anonymous-functions-in-r-python/)

Answer (score 4):

To translate `[i for i, e in enumerate(y) if e != 0]` into R, it helps to describe what it means in words: Get all the indexes of elements in `y` where the element does not equal 0.

In R, many operations are implicitly vectorised, so you can do this:

```
which(y != 0)
```

where `y != 0` returns a logical vector corresponding to whether each element is equal to zero, and `which` returns indexes of a logical vector that are `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks! One more question:
The whole python block is as follows:
    `for i in range(16):
    nofirst=first[:i]+[0.]+first[i+1:]
    total=sum(nofirst)
    cond=[first[i]*z/total for z in nofirst]
    second=[x + y for x,y in zip(second,cond)]`

So far I've built the loop in R like this (it's not quite working):
    `for(i in 1:16) {
      nofirst <- pick1[1:i]+0+pick1[(i+1):16]
      total <- sum(nofirst)
      cond <- (pick1[i]*nofirst/total)[which(x %in% c(nofirst))]
      second=second+cond
    }`